# Laravel post file with HTTP::attach A 'contents' key is required error coming

Tags: php, laravel-8, multipartform-data

I am getting errors on the Laravel post file with HTTP::attach error: A 'contents' key is required

```
static public function apiRequestWithFile($method, $endpoint, array $params = [], $file = null)
    {
        $apiKey = env('API_KEY');
        $baseUrl = env('BASE_URL');

        $file = fopen($file, 'r');

        $response = Http::withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => $apiKey,
            ])->attach('file', $file, 'file.csv')
            ->$method($baseUrl . $endpoint, $params);

        return $response->json();
    }
```

Getting a 'contents' key is required

**Following laravel documentation**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because with attach method, your enctype will be kinda changed to "Multipart/Form-data", so you need to pass your param array like this:

```
$params = [
                [
                    'name' => 'param 1',
                    'contents' => 'param 1 contents'
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'param 2',
                    'contents' => 'param 2 contents'
                ]
];
```